# OpenGL Stencil shadows with geometry shaders

Tags: opengl, geometry-shader

I have forked one OpenSourced project on GitHub and would like to add support for geometry shaders.

This is my fragment code for OpenGL what I am using.

Those two shaders (Fragment and Vertex shaders) are used for "Per Pixel Lighting" calculation (maybe there are bugs)

Fragment Shader

```
#ifdef USE_SHADOW_CUBEMAP
#ifdef USE_SHADOW_CUBESHADOWSAMPLER
#version 130
#extension GL_EXT_gpu_shader4 : enable
#endif // USE_SHADOW_CUBESHADOWSAMPLER
#endif
// shader input
uniform sampler2D colorMap;
uniform vec3 u_lightOrigin;
uniform float u_lightRadius;
// shader varying variables
varying vec3 v_vertXYZ;
varying vec3 v_vertNormal; 

#if defined(HAS_BUMP_MAP) || defined(HAS_HEIGHT_MAP)
//Dushan - only supported in vertex shader
//attribute vec3 atrTangents;
//attribute vec3 atrBinormals;
varying mat3 tbnMat;
#endif
#ifdef HAS_BUMP_MAP
uniform sampler2D bumpMap;
#endif
#ifdef HAS_HEIGHT_MAP
uniform sampler2D heightMap;
varying vec3 v_tbnEyeDir;
#endif
#if defined(HAS_HEIGHT_MAP) && defined(USE_RELIEF_MAPPING)
#include "reliefMappingRaycast.inc"
#endif
#ifdef HAS_LIGHT_COLOR
uniform vec3 u_lightColor;
#endif
#ifdef ENABLE_SHADOW_MAPPING_BLUR
uniform float u_shadowMapSize;
#endif

#ifdef ENABLE_SHADOW_MAPPING_BLUR
float doShadowBlurSample(sampler2DShadow map, vec4 coord)
{
    float shadow = 0.0;

    float pixelOffset = 1.0/u_shadowMapSize;
    //float samples = 0;
    // avoid counter shadow
    if (coord.w > 1.0)
    {
        float x,y;
        for (y = -1.5; y <=1.5; y+=1.0)
        {
            for (x = -1.5; x <=1.5; x+=1.0)
            {
                //if(
                //continue;
                vec4 c = coord + vec4(x * pixelOffset * coord.w, y * pixelOffset * coord.w, 0, 0.0);
                shadow += shadow2DProj(map, c ).w;
                //samples += 1.0;
            }
        }   
        //shadow /= samples;
        shadow /= 16;
    }
    return shadow;
}
#endif

#ifdef SHADOW_MAPPING_SPOTLIGHT
    uniform sampler2DShadow spotLightShadowMap;
    varying vec4 spotShadowCoord;

    float computeSpotLightShadow() {
        float shadow = 0;
        #ifndef ENABLE_SHADOW_MAPPING_BLUR
            shadow += shadow2DProj(spotLightShadowMap, spotShadowCoord).s;
        #else
            shadow += doShadowBlurSample(spotLightShadowMap, spotShadowCoord);
        #endif
        return shadow;
    }


#elif defined(SHADOW_MAPPING_POINT_LIGHT)
uniform mat4 u_entityMatrix;
#ifdef USE_SHADOW_CUBEMAP
    #ifdef USE_SHADOW_CUBESHADOWSAMPLER
        uniform samplerCubeShadow shadowCubeMap;
    #else
        uniform samplerCube shadowCubeMap;
    #endif
#else
    varying vec4 shadowCoord0;
    varying vec4 shadowCoord1;
    varying vec4 shadowCoord2;
    varying vec4 shadowCoord3;
    varying vec4 shadowCoord4;
    varying vec4 shadowCoord5;
    uniform sampler2DShadow shadowMap0;
    uniform sampler2DShadow shadowMap1;
    uniform sampler2DShadow shadowMap2;
    uniform sampler2DShadow shadowMap3;
    uniform sampler2DShadow shadowMap4;
    uniform sampler2DShadow shadowMap5;

    int cubeSide(vec3 v) {
        vec3 normals[] = { vec3(1,0,0), vec3(-1,0,0),
                            vec3(0,-1,0), vec3(0,1,0),
                            vec3(0,0,-1), vec3(0,0,1)}; 
        float max = 0;
        int ret;
        for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            float d = dot(normals[i],v);
            if(d < max) {
                max = d;
                ret = i;
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }
#endif
uniform vec3 u_viewOrigin;
float computeShadow(vec3 lightToVertDirection) {
    float shadow = 0.0;
#ifdef USE_SHADOW_CUBEMAP
#ifdef USE_SHADOW_CUBESHADOWSAMPLER
    vec4 res = shadowCube( shadowCubeMap, vec4(-lightToVertDirection.x,lightToVertDirection.y,lightToVertDirection.z,depth) );
    shadow = res.z;
#else
    float shadowMapDist = textureCube(shadowCubeMap,vec3(-lightToVertDirection.x,lightToVertDirection.y,lightToVertDirection.z)).x;
    float currentLenght = length(lightToVertDirection);
    shadowMapDist *= u_lightRadius;

    float eps = 0.0;
    if(shadowMapDist + eps < currentLenght) {
        shadow = 0.0;
    } else {
        shadow = 1.0;
    }
#endif
#else
    int side = cubeSide(lightToVertDirection);
#ifndef ENABLE_SHADOW_MAPPING_BLUR
    if (side == 0) {
        shadow += shadow2DProj(shadowMap0, shadowCoord0).s;
    } else if(side == 1) {
        shadow += shadow2DProj(shadowMap1, shadowCoord1).s;
    } else if(side == 2) {
        shadow += shadow2DProj(shadowMap2, shadowCoord2).s;
    } else if(side == 3) {
        shadow += shadow2DProj(shadowMap3, shadowCoord3).s;
    } else if(side == 4) {
        shadow += shadow2DProj(shadowMap4, shadowCoord4).s;
    } else if(side == 5) {
        shadow += shadow2DProj(shadowMap5, shadowCoord5).s;
    } else {
        // never gets here
    }
#else
    if (side == 0) {
        shadow += doShadowBlurSample(shadowMap0, shadowCoord0);
    } else if(side == 1) {
        shadow += doShadowBlurSample(shadowMap1, shadowCoord1);
    } else if(side == 2) {
        shadow += doShadowBlurSample(shadowMap2, shadowCoord2);
    } else if(side == 3) {
        shadow += doShadowBlurSample(shadowMap3, shadowCoord3);
    } else if(side == 4) {
        shadow += doShadowBlurSample(shadowMap4, shadowCoord4);
    } else if(side == 5) {
        shadow += doShadowBlurSample(shadowMap5, shadowCoord5);
    } else {
        // never gets here
    }
#endif
#endif
    return shadow;
}
#endif // SHADOW_MAPPING_POINT_LIGHT

#ifdef LIGHT_IS_SPOTLIGHT
uniform vec3 u_lightDir;
uniform float u_spotLightMaxCos;
#endif

// #ifdef HAS_DOOM3_ALPHATEST
// uniform float u_alphaTestValue;
// #endif

void main() {
#if 0
    gl_FragColor.rgb = v_vertNormal;
    return;
#endif
    // calculate texcoord
#ifdef HAS_HEIGHT_MAP
    vec3 eyeDirNormalized = normalize(v_tbnEyeDir);
#ifdef USE_RELIEF_MAPPING
    // relief mapping
    vec2 texCoord = ReliefMappingRayCast(gl_TexCoord[0].xy,eyeDirNormalized);
#else
    // simple height mapping
    vec4 offset = texture2D(heightMap, gl_TexCoord[0].xy);
    offset = offset * 0.05 - 0.02;
    vec2 texCoord = offset.xy * eyeDirNormalized.xy +  gl_TexCoord[0].xy;   
#endif
#else
    vec2 texCoord = gl_TexCoord[0].st;
#endif 
    // calculate light direction and distance to current pixel
    vec3 lightToVert = u_lightOrigin - v_vertXYZ;
    float distance = length(lightToVert);
    if(distance > u_lightRadius) {
        // pixel is too far from the ligh
        return;
    }
    vec3 lightDirection = normalize(lightToVert);

#ifdef LIGHT_IS_SPOTLIGHT
    float spotDOT = dot(lightDirection,u_lightDir);
    if(-spotDOT < u_spotLightMaxCos) {
        return;
    }
#endif


#ifdef HAS_BUMP_MAP
    vec3 bumpMapNormal = texture2D (bumpMap, texCoord).xyz;
    bumpMapNormal = (bumpMapNormal - 0.5) * 2.0;
    vec3 useNormal = tbnMat * bumpMapNormal;
#else
    vec3 useNormal = v_vertNormal;
#endif
    // calculate the diffuse value based on light angle 
    float angleFactor = dot(useNormal, lightDirection);
#ifdef MATERIAL_TWO_SIDED
    angleFactor = abs(angleFactor);
#endif
    if(angleFactor < 0.0) {
        // light is behind the surface
        return;
    }
#ifdef DEBUG_IGNOREANGLEFACTOR
    angleFactor = 1.0;
#endif // DEBUG_IGNOREANGLEFACTOR  
    //  apply distnace scale
    float distanceFactor = 1.0 - distance / u_lightRadius;

#ifdef DEBUG_IGNOREDISTANCEFACTOR
    distanceFactor = 1.0;
#endif // DEBUG_IGNOREDISTANCEFACTOR

#ifdef SHADOW_MAPPING_POINT_LIGHT
    vec4 lightWorld = (u_entityMatrix) * vec4(u_lightOrigin,1);
    vec4 vertWorld = (u_entityMatrix) * vec4(v_vertXYZ,1);
    vec4 lightToVert_world = lightWorld - vertWorld;
    float shadow = computeShadow(lightToVert_world.xyz);
#elif defined(SHADOW_MAPPING_SPOTLIGHT)
    float shadow = computeSpotLightShadow();
#else
    float shadow = 1.0;
#endif

// testing
//#ifdef MATERIAL_TWO_SIDED
//angleFactor = 1.f;
//distanceFactor = 1.f;
//#endif
    vec4 textureColor = texture2D (colorMap, texCoord);
// #ifdef HAS_DOOM3_ALPHATEST
//  if(textureColor.a < u_alphaTestValue)
//  {
//      discard;
//  }
// #endif

    // calculate the final color
    gl_FragColor = textureColor * angleFactor * distanceFactor * shadow;
#ifdef HAS_LIGHT_COLOR
    gl_FragColor.xyz *= u_lightColor;
#endif
    //gl_FragColor = textureCube(shadowCubeMap,vec3(-lightToVert_world.x,lightToVert_world.y,lightToVert_world.z));
#if defined(DEBUG_SHOW_SPOTLIGHT_SHADOWS) && defined(SHADOW_MAPPING_SPOTLIGHT)
    if(shadow < 0.5) {
        gl_FragColor += vec4(1,0,0,1);
    }
#endif
#if defined(DEBUG_SHOW_POINTLIGHT_SHADOWS) && defined(SHADOW_MAPPING_POINT_LIGHT)
    if(shadow < 0.5) {
        gl_FragColor += vec4(0,1,0,1);
    }
#endif
}
```

Vertex Shader

```
// shader varying variables
varying vec3 v_vertXYZ;
varying vec3 v_vertNormal; 
#ifdef SHADOW_MAPPING_SPOTLIGHT
varying vec4 spotShadowCoord;
#elif defined(SHADOW_MAPPING_POINT_LIGHT)
// used for shadow lookup
varying vec4 shadowCoord0;
varying vec4 shadowCoord1;
varying vec4 shadowCoord2;
varying vec4 shadowCoord3;
varying vec4 shadowCoord4;
varying vec4 shadowCoord5;
#endif // SHADOW_MAPPING_POINT_LIGHT
#if defined(HAS_BUMP_MAP) || defined(HAS_HEIGHT_MAP)
attribute vec3 atrTangents;
attribute vec3 atrBinormals;
varying mat3 tbnMat;
#endif
#ifdef HAS_BUMP_MAP
uniform sampler2D bumpMap;
#endif
#ifdef HAS_HEIGHT_MAP
uniform sampler2D heightMap;
varying vec3 v_tbnEyeDir;
uniform vec3 u_viewOrigin;
#endif

void main() {   
#ifdef HAS_HEIGHT_MAP
    // calculate the direction of the viewOrigin from the vertex;
    vec3 dirEye = u_viewOrigin  - gl_Vertex;

    // transform eyeDirection into tangent space
    v_tbnEyeDir.x = dot(atrTangents , dirEye);
    v_tbnEyeDir.y = dot(atrBinormals , dirEye);
    v_tbnEyeDir.z = dot(gl_Normal.xyz , dirEye);
#endif

#ifdef SHADOW_MAPPING_POINT_LIGHT
    // this is the only shadow part in the Vertex Shader
    shadowCoord0 = gl_TextureMatrix[1] * gl_Vertex;
    shadowCoord1 = gl_TextureMatrix[2] * gl_Vertex;
    shadowCoord2 = gl_TextureMatrix[3] * gl_Vertex;
    shadowCoord3 = gl_TextureMatrix[4] * gl_Vertex;
    shadowCoord4 = gl_TextureMatrix[5] * gl_Vertex;
    shadowCoord5 = gl_TextureMatrix[6] * gl_Vertex;
#endif
#ifdef SHADOW_MAPPING_SPOTLIGHT
    spotShadowCoord = gl_TextureMatrix[1] * gl_Vertex;
#endif
    gl_Position = ftransform();
    // this is needed here for GL_CLIP_PLANE0 to work.
    // clipping planes are used by mirrors
    gl_ClipVertex = gl_ModelViewMatrix * gl_Vertex;
#if defined(HAS_BUMP_MAP) || defined(HAS_HEIGHT_MAP)
    tbnMat = mat3(atrTangents,atrBinormals,gl_Normal);
#endif

    v_vertXYZ = gl_Vertex.xyz;
    gl_TexCoord[0] = gl_TextureMatrix[0] * gl_MultiTexCoord0;
    v_vertNormal = normalize(gl_Normal);
}
```

Based on that two shaders can someone show me how to write correctly geometry shaders.
I have tried something, but I always get error from geometry shader about "gl_FragColor"

```
Geometry shader failed to compile with the following errors:
ERROR: 0:8: error(#143) Undeclared identifier: gl_FragColor
ERROR: error(#273) 1 compilation errors.  No code generated
```

I am absolute rookie here with geometry shaders and I never had worked with that in the past, please keep that in mind.

I would like that someone show me example of correct way with explanations how and what should be done.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

gl_FragColor is only available in fragment shader, not geometry shaders.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind replay. I know that it is not supported, but like I said, I am rookie, can you show me how it should geometry shader be written?

Thanks

Comment: Here's a tutorial I've written about geometry shaders: http://www.ogldev.org/www/tutorial27/tutorial27.html  I hope you find it useful.